# how to filter django model object if contains in python django

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am trying to filter out a model which contain sender,receiver,user, the problem is when i try to use `return Private_messages.objects.filter(sender__contains=sender,receiver__contains=receiver,user=user)`

it is strict in checking and will only return if condition are met...

**model example**

```
id:1
sender:"dan"
reciever:"harry"

id:2
sender:"harry"
reciever:"dan"

id:3
sender:"dan"
reciever:"harry"
```

in this sometimes sender is dan sometimes not. with `Private_messages.objects.filter(sender="dan",receiver="dan")`
i want to get all object with the who has sender dan and receiver dan not both dan

how can i get something like this in python django?

Comment: You mean you want to get the results where either sender is Dan or receiver is Dan ?

Comment: yes, all the object where sender is dan or receiver is dan..

Comment: you can do something like this... `from django.db.models import Q
Private_messages.objects.filter(Q(sender="dan") | Q(receiver="dan"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the items where either *sender is dan* **OR** *receiver is dan*. Then you can do this

###### Using Q objects - [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q
ans = Private_messages.objects.filter(Q(sender='dan') | Q(receiver='dan'))
```

##### Using `|`

```
ans = Private_messages.objects.filter(sender='dan') | Private_messages.objects.filter(receiver='dan')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the a union of the following querysets:

```
q1 = Private_messages.objects.filter(sender__contains=sender)
q2 = Private_messages.objects.filter(receiver__contains=receiver)
q3 = Private_messages.objects.filter(user=user)


return q1.union(q2, q3)
```

You can check out more info on the union operation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#union

You could also use Q queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects